# How do I clean the rubber surface on my mouse, which has become sticky over time?

Tags: cleaning

I've had a Razer DeathAdder for a few years. The surface is quite sticky, not like a residue but more clingy.

Wiping with water doesn't work. It gets smooth when wet but straight back to sticky when dry. Drying with cloths usually leaves bits if lint. I've tried all sorts of things like alcohol but nothing helps. I can scratch it with my fingernail and a tiny bit of gunk gets rolled up but it won't really brush off.

It's annoying to use. How can I stop it being so sticky?

Answer (score 0):

I've found buffing it with a damp green scourer works pretty well. It gets really scratched but seems to remove the sticky surface very well.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using corn starch for my Orochi mouse surface which went sticky a while ago.

Apply a light quantity **with dry hands** the most uniform way you can and then remove the excess by gently tapping the mouse and rubbing it with your hand.

This process has to be repeated when the stickyness comes back, which hasn't happened to be that often for myself.